# ElasticBeanstalk Docker, one Container or multiple Containers?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, celery, supervisord

We are working on a new REST API that will be deployed on AWS ElasticBeanstalk using Docker. It uses Python Celery for scheduled jobs which means separate process need to run for workers, our current Docker configuration has three containers...

Multicontainer Docker:

```
09c3182122f7    sso    "gunicorn --reload --"    18 hours ago    Up 26 seconds                            sso-api
f627c5391ee8    sso    "celery -A sso worker"    18 hours ago    Up 27 seconds                            sso-worker
f627c5391ee8    sso    "celery beat -A sso -"    18 hours ago    Up 27 seconds                            sso-beat
```

Conventional wisdom would suggest we should use a Multi-container configuration on ElasticBeanstalk but since all containers use the same code, using a single container configuration with Supervisord to manage processes might be more efficient and simpler from an OPS point of view.

Single Container w/ Supervisord:

```
[program:api]
command=gunicorn --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --pythonpath '/var/sso' sso.wsgi:application
directory=/var/sso

[program:worker]
command=celery -A sso worker -l info
directory=/var/sso
numprocs=2

[program:beat]
command=celery beat -A sso -S djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler
directory=/var/sso
```

When setting up a multi-container configuration on AWS memory is allocated to each container, my thinking is it more efficient to let the container OS handle memory allocation internally rather than to explicitly set it to each container. I do not know enough about how Multi-container Docker runs under the hood on ElasticBeanstalk to intelligently recommend one way or the other.

What is the optimal configuration for this situation?

Comment: IMHO putting all within a single container might have clear drawbacks, like having a supervisor'ed program (or all) in FATAL state. From a container's perspective everything is up (supervisor and the other programs are up). Also pushing changes to a single component would affect others within its shared container. When working with multicontainer Elastic Beanstalk, if one container crashes it will be restarted automatically, can be monitored easier, etc. 
Definitely I would go to a microservices approach based in multiple containers due to its benefits from an ops perspective.

Comment: You raise a very good point about supervisor programs failing but the application marked as online since supervisor is still running. It did feel to me though that from a memory optimization point of view, a single container would be more efficient. Does AWS do anything under the hood to manage memory for idle containers? The memory element may seem trivial but when you start to scale it matters a lot. Or do we just have to decide on performance efficiency vs stability of OPS?

Comment: As far as I understood, memory usage will depend on whether deduplication is possible on the ec2 instance used by EB. Depending on the underlying fs page sharing will be possible, mitigating the possible memory issues. More on that here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7950.

Comment: I ask the question regarding memory because EB asks you to explicitly set memory per container when creating a multi-container docker environment.

Comment: Given that, let's compare a big container with 3 supervised services vs 3 containers each with its service. Assuming page caching is possible (aufs or overlayfs) the latter will use approximately the same resources plus gives you more flexibility and stability. If that's not the case (i.e. btrfs or devicemapper) then you'll be using some extra MB for the 2nd option. For both scenarios you'll require less memory for the containers than embedding several services into a single container.